# How to include clock_gettime in a c make file

Tags: c

I know that in order to use the `clock_gettime(2)` function, you have to include `-lrt` in the makefile but I have no idea where it goes. Where would I put it in the example makefile.

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c99
CC = gcc

objects = example.o

example: $(objects)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o example $(objects)

example.o: example.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c example.c
clean:
    rm test $(objects)
```

Edit: how my lrt looks.

[image]

[image]

What my code is:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct timespec starttime, endtime;
    double elapsed;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &starttime);

    /// work to be timed

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &endtime);
    elapsed = ((endtime.tv_sec-starttime.tv_sec)*1000000000.0 + (endtime.tv_nsec - starttime.tv_nsec))/1000000000;
    // elapsed time can also be calculated as
    if (endtime.tv_nsec < starttime.tv_nsec) {
        // borrow a second
        elapsed = (endtime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec - 1) + (1000000000.0 + endtime.tv_nsec - starttime.tv_nsec)/1000000000;
    }
    else {
        elapsed = (endtime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec ) + (endtime.tv_nsec - starttime.tv_nsec)/1000000000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it's `-lrt`, not `-1rt` (it's an 'L', not the digit '1'). You need to put it on the line that builds the executable (so, in the line after `example: $(objects)`). Make sure it's the last thing on that line.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves i changed it to lower case L but it still looks different. Does it have to look exactly like yours because in TextEdit it looks different.

Comment: It's a lower-case 'L'. I just typed upper-case to show the difference. See dbush's answer, that's what you need.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves edited my question. Added a picture of how lrt looks in my text editor. Is the font of the l causing it to not work?

Comment: It looks good. I would suggest posting the actual error message (or describe whatever problem you're having); that might be a better clue for us to help you.

Comment: The font has nothing to do with it.  As long as it's a lower case L it should be fine.  If it's still not working, post the error message.

Comment: See my answer. You need to include `time.h` in the source code.

Comment: @dbush posted it, my code looks exactly like ritesh posted, and I'm importing time.h and I'm still getting those errors.

Comment: If that's the case, then something else is off.  Please post your code (in text format, not a screenshot) so we can get more context on what your error is.

Comment: @dbush added the code

Comment: It compiles fine for me with `gcc -Wall -o /tmp/x1 /tmp/x1.c -lrt`

Answer (score 3):

You want to put it on the line that links the executable.  Namely, the line that specifies the `-o` option.  That's where the linker phase is carried out.

```
example: $(objects)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o example $(objects) -lrt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c99
CC = gcc
LDFLAGS = -lrt

objects = example.o

example: $(objects)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o example $(objects) $(LDFLAGS)

example.o: example.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c example.c
clean:
    rm test $(objects)
```

As this is linker option, so its best to use as LDFLAGS variable which is common practice in Makefiles.

Comment: LDLIBS for libraries, LDFLAGS for other linker options, usually. Of course you can call it whatever you want as long as you don't need implicit rules to work.

Comment: @Wumpus I agree with you.

Comment: @Ritesh, that is confusing.  You agree you don't need implicit rules to work?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but your problem seems to be that you're not including the necessary header files.

Add this in your source code:

```
#include <time.h>
```